# Error while creating a tumbling window in Apache Flink Java

Tags: java, apache-flink

I try to create a tumbling time window of 2 rows each in Flink Java. This must based on the dateTime (TimeStamp3 datatype) or unixDateTime(BIGINT datatype) column.  I've added code of two different code version. The error I get I placed above the code.

When I print the datatypes of the `Table` object I see this: 
 `|-- mID: INT
 |-- dateTime: TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*
 |-- mValue: DOUBLE
 |-- unixDateTime: BIGINT
 |-- mType: STRING`

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment fsEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(fsEnv);   
        fsEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

    TupleTypeInfo<Tuple5<Integer, Timestamp, Double, Long, String>> tupleType = new TupleTypeInfo<>(
        Types.INT(),
        Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(),
        Types.DOUBLE(),
        Types.LONG(),
        Types.STRING());
        DataStream<Tuple5<Integer, Timestamp, Double, Long, String>> dsTuple =
                tableEnv.toAppendStream(HTable, tupleType);

//When I run below code I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Rowtime timestamp is null. Please make sure that a proper TimestampAssigner is defined and the stream environment uses the EventTime time characteristic.

Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dsTuple, "mID, dateTime.rowtime, mValue, unixDateTime, mType");
   DataStream<Row> stream = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);
stream.print();

//When I run below code I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Event-time grouping windows on row intervals are currently not supported.

   Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dsTuple, "mID, dateTime.rowtime, measurementValue, unixDateTime, measurementType")
.window(Tumble.over("2.rows")
.on("dateTime")
.as("a"))
.groupBy("a")
.select("AVG(mValue)");
    DataStream<Row> stream = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);
    stream.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Time based operations on streaming tables require that you explicitly inform Flink about how time is to be handled. You'll want to read the [relevant section of the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html).

You'll want to pay particular attention to the section on [event time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#event-time).

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I implemented your solution but now I get new errors. I edited my question above on the new situation. U know how to solve this errors? Is there some workaround?